# How to get the entity of the quote type in wordpress

Tags: php, mysql, wordpress

I get a list of all posts using the get_posts() hook.
Can I get all the quotes in a similar way?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, you need to add post_type argument
[ref :](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/get_posts/#user-contributed-notes)

```
$args = array(
  'numberposts' => 10,
  'post_type'   => 'quote'
);

$latest_books = get_posts( $args );
```